# Re-importing specific tables from Oracle dump file

Tags: database, oracle, import

I imported a full oracle dump file into my database schema using the following command in linux ssh.

```
    impdp system/password directory=bckup schemas=sch101 dumpfile=sc101.dmp    remap_schema=sch101:MY_SCHEMA TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=APPEND;
```

This command imported must of the tables into me target schema but some of the tables were skipped due to some constraint error.
I wanted to try to import these tables into my database after fixing the problem one by one. I used following command for doing so,

```
    impdp system/password DIRECTORY=bckup TABLES=TBL_NAME DUMPFILE=sch101.dmp remap_schema=sch101:MY_SCHEMA TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=APPEND;
```

But this command returns me error:

```
    ORA-39002: invalid operation
    ORA-39166: Object SYSTEM.TBL_NAME was not found.
```

I checked the name of the tables I tried to import in the export log file of the dump file that I used and they exist in the dump file. 
What is that silly mistake that I am doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're importing as `system` from what is presumably a full (not schema) export, you need to specify the schema name in the [`tables` parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL937), despite the presence of the `schema` parameter:

```
... TABLES=sch101.TBL_NAME ...
```

The error message you're getting refers to `SYSTEM.TBL_NAME`, which clearly (or hopefully, anyway) isn't what you want.

Comment: 'despite the presence of the schema parameter'. I tried this and it doesn' work that way because in impdp you can either specify the schema or the tables parameter, not both. That is why we need to qualify the table with schema.

Comment: I might have meant the `remap_schema` parameter, but it was a long time ago... You're right that you can't specify both `tables` and 'schema` - that's why you need the schema as a prefix to a table name instead.